# how to insert data into many many relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpmyadmin

i have a table that has four IDs of different models, they have a relationship of many to many

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('district_group_project_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->uuid('district_id');
        $table->uuid('group_id');
        $table->uuid('project_id');
        $table->uuid('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

now i like to save the data in the following table I used the relationship to function in each model in project.php

```
    public function users()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'district_group_project_user');
}
```

in other too i used same type of function and in the user controller i want to attach

```
        $user->project()->attach($request->district,$request->userGroup,$request->project);
```

it does not save, any idea how to save the following values one time

Answer (score 0):

you can use [newPivotQuery](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_newPivotQuery) Method, witch make the query relative to the pivot table:

```
 $user->project()->newPivotQuery()
            ->insert(['user_id'=>$user_id,'project_id'=>$request->project,
'group_id'=>$request->userGroup,'district_id'=>$request->district])
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply it show an error "Array to string conversion"